# Mysql Select по нескольким значениям одного поля

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица
users
user_id | user_name | user_groups
1 | Ваня | 1 , 3

groups
group_id | group_name |
1 | one
2 | two
3 | three

Соответственно, в таблице users в поле user_groups указаны id в таблице groups.
Нужно выдернуть Ваню с его первой и третьей группой.
SELECT * FROM users AS A left JOIN groups AS B ON B.group_id IN( A.user_groups) выводит  только первое значение.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный запрос

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [тут](http://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=37304).

Comment: и..все равно не ясно.может не туда смотрю?
запрос  ON B.group_id IN (1,3) отработает.  
а с значением в виде ON B.group_id IN (A.user_groups). где A.user_groups и есть "1,3", возвращает лишь первое значение..

Comment: @astimated, вам [сюда](http://hashcode.ru/questions/355411/mysql-запрос-для-выбора-нескольких-значений-по-id-через-запятую). Если коротко, то так делать не стоит, @Daniel-664 правильно отметил.

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя было создать таблицу с полями

```
user_id | group_id
```

Было бы тогда только

```
user_id | user_name
group_id | group_name
```

А первая таблица указывала бы на принадлежность пользователя к группе, и не пришлось бы строить сложных запросов. Если оставить текущую структуру, то вам придется извлекать из одного поля сразу несколько значений. Попробуйте использовать оператор LIKE или, возможно, регулярные выражения.

Comment: так и создал в итоге.
у нас три таблицы.
в первой берем пользователя, во второй ищем группы, в которых он состоит, из третьей вынимаем уже сами группы, так?  
SELECT g.*,u.*
FROM groups g
  INNER JOIN user_groups ug
    ON g.id=ug.user_groups
  INNER JOIN users u
    ON ug.user_id=u.id
WHERE u.id=1

Comment: Да, такая структура действительно считается наиболее правильной и предпочтительной.